# Listview, Bitmaps and FastScroll strange heap allocation

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, fastscroll

I have a strange allocation issue on a listview, populated with LOTS of views with bitmaps.

The strange thing is that if I scroll down the list manually, the system allocates more and more space on the heap and the app crashes with an infamous OutOfMemory. If I scroll down the list instead with fastscroll, the system correctly frees the heap! Of course, I reuse views...

Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: My fault! It was a damn leak!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LazyLoad images,

[LazyList Github](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

and

[LazyList Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/790810)